# Introductory book on Hyperbolic Geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, hyperbolic-geometry

I am looking for an introductory book on "Hyperbolic Geometry" for self-study.
What is the gentlest note/book on this subject.
Free online book or a PDF would be much better.
I really appreciate that any help you can provide.

(I am familiar with complex variables but not with differential geometry)

Comment: ["Journey into Geometries" by Marta Sved](https://www.amazon.com/Journey-into-Geometries-Spectrum-Marta/dp/0883855003) is a pretty fun intro, written as an Alice-in-Wonderland-style narrative (in which Lewis Carroll is a character). More formally, I learned from [Marvin Greenberg's "Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries"](https://www.amazon.com/Euclidean-Non-Euclidean-Geometries-Development-History/dp/0716799480).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think also Marvin Greenbergs“Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries: Development and History" 
 Is a good way to start but would advise against the expensive 4th edition  maybe best to start with a second hand copy of an earlier version.

But I am a bit wondering what do you want to learn about hyperbolic geometry for subfields there are better introductions

Good luck